# Copy and paste data from different worksheet to another worksheet in a same excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Save7()
Dim NextRow As Range
Set NextRow = Range("AC" & Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count)
Sheet3.Range("AC14:AG14").Copy
Sheet1.Activate
NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set NextRow = Nothing
End Sub
```

My purpose of this code is to copy data ( Five columns of 'NO' in AC14 to AG14) from sheet 3 and paste to sheet 1 where the last active cell is at.

The code above is working well, however I made some modification to the sheet tab name for sheet 1. Sheet 1 is now called "Equipment stuffs", while sheet 3 name is remaining unchanged.

After those changes, the macro stopped working. The cause is probably because I don't know how to declare "Equipment stuffs" in the code .

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do copy/paste to move data from one place on the spreadsheet to another. You should simply assign the Value of the respective Range objects, for example:

```
Sheet1.Range("NamedRange2").Value = Sheet1.Range("NamedRange2").Value
```

Also, use code names for the sheets, instead of `Sheets("SheetName")`, and defined named for the ranges, instead of `Range("AC14:AG14"`, otherwise your code will stop working if the user renames the sheet or inserts or deletes any rows above your reference.

Comment: I will ask my colleagues not to touch sheet 3 in this case. So how can i declare 'equipment stuff' in the above code to make it work ? i am quite clueless in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate this a little you could collect the active workbook and loop through each sheet using `wb.Worksheets`. Then collect the name with `targetSheet.Name`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getSheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each targetSheet In wb.Worksheets
        Debug.Print targetSheet.Name
    Next targetSheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m brazilian hehe, I understood your  question , I’ve  a code  for alter  the data  in same worksheet (I’ll attach it here), for you to change the data in another worksheet, you need put on:

Worksheets("NameWorkSheet) Activate

for the VBA that’s refers  to this tab.

Comment: While (Cells(linha, 1)) <> ""
        If (alterar.idProduto = Cells(linha, 1)) Then
            Cells(linha, 1) = alterar.idProduto
            Cells(linha, 2) = alterar.data_Validade
            Cells(linha, 3) = alterar.tipo_do_Produto
            Cells(linha, 4) = alterar.lote_Produto
            Cells(linha, 5) = alterar.fabricante
            Cells(linha, 6) = alterar.fazer
            linha = linha + 1
            naoAchou = True
        Else
            linha = linha + 1
        End If
    Wend 
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub